# IsPrefixOf not working correctly during pattern matching segment

Tags: string, haskell, prefix

I am very new to Haskell. I have a a list which is acting as a database and i want to search the titles of the list with a prefix that you can insert. The type data for the titles is [String]

Finally managed to make the code compile but instead of searching for a prefix the function only works if the full title is inserted. So for example I would like to search ["G"] and have the two results pop up but unless the full title is entered the search garners no results.

```
-- Types
type Title = [String]
type Artist = [String]
type Year = Int
type Sales = Int

-- Define Album type here
type Album  =  (Title, Artist, Year, Sales)

-- Define database type here
type Database = [Album]
```

Then the database follows this pattern

```
[(["Greatest Hits"                 ],        [ "Queen"          ],   1981,    6300000),
(["Gold: Greatest Hits"            ],        [ "ABBA"           ],   1992,   5400000),
...
```

-

```
- Detects if the prefix is in the string ahead of it
    searchByPrefix :: [String] -> Album -> Bool
    searchByPrefix prefx (t, a, y, s)
      | isPrefixOf prefx t = True
      | otherwise = False

    -- A function that displays all the albums by a certain artist
    displayAlbumsByPrefix :: [String] -> Database ->  String
    displayAlbumsByPrefix prefx database = albumsToString (filter (searchByPrefix (prefx)) database)
```

Where albumsToString is just a function that displays the database neatly.

I understand the issue is probably a massive oversight.

Comment: So `Album` is something like `(String, a, b, c)` and `Database` is `[Album]`? Please provide a *complete* example that demonstrates what you code does that diverges from your expectation.

Comment: And if this is related to https://stackoverflow.com/q/55855747/1126841, don't you guys have a  teacher you can ask?

Comment: You know that as you've currently typed it, `["Uriah"]` would constitute a valid prefix for `["Uriah", "Heep"]`, but `["Uri"]`would not, don't you?

Comment: So the function is looking for the first element in the list as a prefix? when i want it too be looking for characters as a prefix instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've maybe formed the impression that the type for strings in Haskell is `[String]`.  However, this type represents a **list** of strings, not a single string.  The type for a single string is just `String`.

As a result, your choice of these types is a little odd:

```
type Title = [String]
type Artist = [String]
```

This means that each album:

```
type Album  =  (Title, Artist, Year, Sales)
```

has a `Title` that's a **list** of strings and an `Artist` that's a **list** of strings.  I guess I can see that you might want multiple artists (though then the type should perhaps be named `Artists` in plural form), but I think that a single string for the album title ought to be enough.

The reason I bring this up is that there's an ambiguity in what your function `displayAlbumsByPrefix` should do if there's an entry like this in the database:

```
...
(["Dark Side of the Moon", "Gold CD Ultradisc Re-release"], ["Pink Floyd"], 1979, 2520000),
...
```

Should it be included in the list generated by a `displayAlbumsByPrefix ["G"]` call?  Or are you checking only the prefix of the first string in the `Title` list?  What if there's an entry in the database where the title is an empty list `[]`?

Anyway, let's set that aside and assume you want to stick with your current code, that by convention the database will always include titles that are lists of exactly one string `["like this"]`, and that you want to filter on the prefix of that string.

In that case, you're almost there.  The code:

```
searchByPrefix :: [String] -> Album -> Bool
searchByPrefix prefx (t, a, y, s)
  | isPrefixOf prefx t = True
  | otherwise = False
```

when called as, say:

```
searchByPrefix ["G"] (["Greatest Hits"],["Queen"],...)
```

creates the argument bindings `prefx=["G"]` and `t=["Greatest Hits"]`.  The `isPrefixOf` call checks to see if the one-element list `["G"]` is a prefix of the one-element list `["Greatest Hits"]` -- in other words, is the element `"G"` equal to `"Greatest Hits"`.  That's clearly `False` which is why your code isn't doing what you want.  Compare the following to see what's going on:

```
> isPrefixOf ["G"] ["Goo"]    -- False  -- string "G" is not equal to string "Goo"
> isPrefixOf "G" "Goo"        -- True   -- character 'G' is equal to character 'G'
```

You can fix this by calling `isPrefixOf` on the heads of the lists instead of the lists themselves:

```
searchByPrefix :: [String] -> Album -> Bool
searchByPrefix prefx (t, a, y, s)
  | isPrefixOf (head prefx) (head t) = True  -- change this line
  | otherwise = False
```

This will fail with a runtime error if either the prefix or the title list in a database record are empty, and it will silently ignore any additional elements after the first in these lists.

You could also do the same thing via a pattern match instead:

```
searchByPrefix :: [String] -> Album -> Bool
searchByPrefix [prefx] ([t], a, y, s)   -- or change this line
  | isPrefixOf prefx t = True
  | otherwise = False
```

and this version will fail with a runtime error if the database contains a record with a `Title` that's something other than a one-element list, or if `searchByPrefix` is called with a prefix other than a one-element list.  (So extra elements will cause a runtime error instead of being silently ignored.)